# gitlab Rack_Attack settings

Tags: gitlab

I have a gitlab CE installation with Rack_Attack enabled, but I am not able to find the current values set for the following parameters - `max_retry`, `findtime`, and `bantime`.

So, where and how can I check the values of these parameters in my gitlab installation?

Answer (score 0):

If you installed the Omnibus GitLab version, the settings can be found in `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb`:

```
gitlab_rails['rack_attack_git_basic_auth'] = {
  'enabled' => true,
  'ip_whitelist' => ["127.0.0.1"],
  'maxretry' => 10,
  'findtime' => 60,
  'bantime' => 3600
}
```

If you installed GitLab from source, the settings can be found in `config/initializers/rack_attack.rb`.

From [the Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/security/rack_attack.html#settings).